# Retrieve values with pdo and store them into array

Tags: php, pdo

i am trying to retrieve from database some values. After i retrieve them i want to store them into an array and this array send it via json. Unfortunately, i'm into error and i cant find any solution.
Can you help me?

```
<?php 
    include_once 'database.php';
    $unique_id = 1;//$_GET['id'];
     try {
     $results = $db->prepare("
        SELECT image_id,image_url,offer_id
        FROM `Images`
        WHERE offer_id = ?");
        $results->bindValue(1, $unique_id);
        $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
        exit;
    }

    $product = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       if($product['image_url'] != ''){
        $arr="".$product['image_url']."";
        //print_r($arr);
        foreach($arr as $file){ //get an array which has the names of all the files and loop through it 
        $obj['name'] = $file;//get the filename in array
        $obj['size'] = filesize("uploads/".$file); //get the flesize in array
        $result[] = $obj; // copy it to another array
         }
       header('Content-Type: application/json');
       echo json_encode($result); // now you have a json response which you can use in client side 
        }

?>
```

Rendered

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/uploads/upload_get.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: result in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/uploads/upload_get.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
null
```

Comment: You're defining `$arr` as a string right before you're trying to use it as an array. If you want to get all the records in an array, you should use `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead

Comment: You obviously don't understand what's happening in your code)

Comment: I recommend that you go through some PHP + PDO tutorials because there are too many things wrong here.

Comment: Thank you. I usually use oophp. I find this tutorial and i am trying to find a solution.